# Setting the range of a CSpinButtonCtrl

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, spinner, cedit

I have four [`CSpinButtonCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cspinbuttonctrl-class?view=msvc-170) objects on my dialog.

They are all configured as:

- Auto Buddy
- Buddy Integer

The respective `CEdit` objects map to `int` variables and the maximum range is set to `0-20`. Now I need the spin controls to match.

---

I know that I can map the spin controls to `CSpinButtonCtrl` variables and them use [`SetRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cspinbuttonctrl-class?view=msvc-170#setrange) but I was hoping to avoid the need to create the variables. Some controls come with macro counterparts that take the `HWND`. Can a simple macro counterpart be created here so that I can set all the ranges to `0-20`?

Comment: The final paragraph reads like you have something like the [`ON_CONTROL_RANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc#on_control_range) macro in mind. In that case, no. MFC supplies macros to register a callback to multiple control ID's. It doesn't provide a way to *execute* a piece of code against multiple controls. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah. I guess the easiest is to use the method to get the control from the ID and cast to spinner. Then run SetRange. That could be a lambda function that I call 4 times in OnInitDialog.

Comment: Now, you *can* gather the set of controls and [`for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) over them, applying either a cast, or sending a `UDM_SETRANGE32` message, but honestly, someone's got to read and debug that code, eventually. And if that someone is you, you'll start to appreciate a simple `for`-loop, when all you have is a crash dump, and debug symbols lost to history.

Comment: @IInspectable Alright. I think it simplest that I map to variables then.